# navigator.geolocation giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm working on a webapp that can use geolocation to do cool things, and right now I'm just lost because navigator.geolocation is giving me wrong results.

My debug code :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(p) {console.log(p.coords)},
    function(p) {console.log('bug')},
    {enableHighAccuracy: true}
)
```

the result :

```
Coordinates {speed: null, heading: null, altitudeAccuracy: null, accuracy:  140843, altitude: null…}
    accuracy: 140843
    altitude: null
    altitudeAccuracy: null
    heading: null
    latitude: 46.1902742
    longitude: 6.1464840999999995
    ...
```

The problem is : The coordinates are plain wrong. [I'm not in Geneva at all](https://www.google.ch/maps/@46.1902742,6.146484,13z?hl=en). I'm in [another part of Switzerland.](https://www.google.ch/maps/@46.2319547,7.3757947,13z?hl=en)

And this problem happens on my computer, on my friend computer, on linux computers, on windows computers, on mac computers.

What is the problem ? Is navigator.geolocation obselet ? not working in switzerland ? I'm just missing something ?

Comment: are you using same internet connection always? Is a VPN? Lan/VPN connections can be redirected through other physical places.

Comment: it is a lan connection, same corporate network. But I've set no VPN up (and I'm managing that network).

Comment: 140km is a really high value for `accuracy`... Have you tried enabling `enableHighAccuracy` in the options? [.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition), [PositionOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

Comment: yeah, same results (edited the main to add it)

Comment: What if you try another site that tells you your location? I mean, same network, other website? Such as http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: In that case I think there's nothing wrong with your code. Desktop computers and most laptops don't have a GPS receiver so other techniques are used and I think the position of some server is being returned.

Comment: This has some information on how else it gets your position: http://www.andygup.net/html5-geolocation-api-%E2%80%93-how-accurate-is-it-really/

Comment: Mhhh, I developped that thing back in Paris, and the navigator.geoloc was really precise.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have GPS-dongle connected to PC ? Or geolocation source is any wrong IP-geo tool or Wifi/Cell. You can't get your exact physical coordinates by IP-address. If you use WiFi network accuracy can be 5-50 meters, but you are using LAN. Geolocation by IP is very very inaccurate, it's normaly to get wrong city or country.

Comment: No GPS-dongle. But I don't know what is the geolocation source.

Comment: If you can edit a little bit your answer to contains the actual answer, I'll mark it as the answer, thank you by the way

Comment: This is freaking weird, cause on WIFI I got nice results, on LAN i got wrong results. Same network. Same wifi-router

Comment: Google has very big database with details for almost all Wifi-routers worldwide. When any person is connected to any WiFi-router via smartphone with turned on GPS, Google saves to database current latitude, longitude, router's SSID, MAC-address, signal-level and password if you agree. When you try to get geolocation via PC connected to WiFi, Google receives list containing all currently visible neighbor's WiFi-routers and their signal-levels, not only your router ! Then Google calculates your approximate coordinates.

Comment: In my browser it shows extremely incorrect location. I mean it is the other part of the earth. I am from India at it shows France. Funny thing is ip location is far more accurate. IP location shows the city i am currently in but geo location shows France